# Laravel 5.1 - Select Option

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1

```
{!! Form::select('name', $names) !!}
```

Here $names is my array and it comes from controller.

```
$names = ['1'=>'John','2'=>'Patric','3'=>'Deny'];
```

Actually i want it from .env file.
I got a single variable from .env file but i don't have any idea to get an array from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Dotenv/env() there is no way you can get an array just by calling env(VAR). You can add separators to your values in .env and then explode it.

You could also use a config .php file and define your array there then return the desired value defined via .env

Answer (score 0):

Is not possible to retrieve an array from the `.env` file, but, you can retrieve one from the `config` settings.

To do this you can create a file inside the `/config` directory and get its values with `\Config::get()`. Example:

You create a file named `custom.php` inside the `config` directory, and inside of the file you write the following.

```
return [
    'modules' => [
        // Array of Modules
    ]
];
```

You can retrieve the `modules` array doing `\Config::get('custom.modules')`.